# Conectar desde Windows a Ubuntu Server virtual

Tags: postgresql

Necesito conectar desde mi equipo host Windows 10 a una base de datos que tengo en Ubuntu Server 20.04 que he instalado en VirtualBox. Cuando lo hago, me da este fallo:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is
> the server running on host "192.168.1.66" and accepting TCP/IP
> connections on port 5432?

¿Alguna solución?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de error te da pistas. No puede conectarse al postgres, encuentra el puerto cerrado.

Por defecto el servidor postgres viene solo escuchando a `127.0.0.1`, o sea el mismo SO Ubuntu. Tienes que dirle a postgres que escuche cualquiera IP.

#### solución:

*debes conocer la version de postgres para entrar al directorio de configuración, en ubuntu 20 tendrás seguramente la 12*

1. Edita fichero `etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf`

   Busca el campo `listen_addresses` y dejalo así: `listen_addresses = '*'`

   Quedará así:

   ```
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      # CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
      #------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      # - Connection Settings -

      listen_addresses = '*'       # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                   # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                   # (change requires restart)
   ```
2. Edita fichero `/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf`

   Busca el comentario `#IPv4 all connections:`

   En la siguiente linea substituye `127.0.0.1/32` por `all`
   quedando así:

   ```
      # IPv4 local connections:
      host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5
   ```
3. Reinicia el servicio postgres `systemctl restart postgresql`

Una vez realizado esos tres pasos veras que podrás entrar, o si hay mensaje de error no será de puerto bloqueado

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta tan bien explicada. Me he dado cuenta, además, de que estaba poniendo mal la IP de conexión, ya que me estaba fijando en "enp0s3" en lugar de en "lo". Entiendo que debo hacerlo así, ¿verdad?

Comment: lo = loopback = 127.0.0.1   , no te acabo de entender...

Comment: Que estaba poniendo la IP que me daba el adaptador enp0s3 en lugar de 127.0.0.1